# Magento 2 : disable cache for static block

Tags: magento2, cache, static-block

In Magento, I can disable cache for static block by add cache_lifetime="null".

```
{{block type="core/template" cache_lifetime="null" title="BEST SELER!!!" sku="ASS030530010" template="catalog/product/menuproduct.phtml"}}
```

How can I disable cache for static block on Magento 2?

Comment: Don't try to disable the cache. If it will disable the whole page cache of the page which contains this block. It will be the bad advice.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I know it. But I have add login link so, I must check if customer login or not. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
{{block type="core/template" cacheable="false" title="BEST SELER!!!" sku="ASS030530010" template="catalog/product/menuproduct.phtml"}}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I have try add cacheable="false" but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: cacheable="false" should work, redeploy and upgrade.

Comment: Thank you! I tried but it doesn't it still show login after I logged.